# How to create a LVM and ext4 file system using lvcreate command only

Tags: lvm

How to create a LVM and ext4 file system using lvcreate command only. is there any swich in lvcreate command to include the file system type?

Answer (score 1):

There is none, and there shouldn't be: A logical volume (i.e. a block device) and a file system are two very different concepts:

- A file system can exist without at block device (i.e. NFS)
- A block device an exist without a file system (i.e. LVM as a VM vbd)

It might be, that the easiest way to achive what you want is a short shell script (maybe called `lvcreateext4`), that calls `lvcreate` and `mkfs.ext4`, then use it instead of lvcreate.